# How to check if stdout of a program is in a file?

Tags: bash, macos, grep

I've attempted numerous times and tried different methods but cannot seem to get this to work. I am trying to run a python script and grep the output to see if it is contained in a file and if it is not I want to append it to said file.

```
$./scan_network.py 22 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20 | if ! grep -q - ./results.log; then - >> results.log; fi
```

I understand that it macOS grep does not understand - as stdout and that then - >> would not work because it would not pick up stdout either. I am not sure what to do.

As stated before the primary goal is to check the output of the script against a file and if the IP address is not found in the file, it needs to be appended.

Edit:

results.log is currently an empty file. Output of scan_network.py on would be 192.168.1.6 for now. When I go to run it on another network the output would be numerous addresses in a range example being 10.234.x.y where x and y would be any number between 0 and 255.

Comment: "grep the output to see if it is contained in a file" is quite hard to parse, probably because I don't know what you mean by "grep". (I know what I mean by "grep", but it's obviously not the same.) I *think* you mean "check each line in the output to see if it is already found in a file". Is that correct? If so, your actual problem is to "find all lines in the output of a program which are not currently in a file, and add them to the file." That's easily solvable but the solution doesn't use the grep utility.

Comment: That would be the correct way of looking at it @rici I am used to running commands like ps aux and so on and piping that through grep so I wasn't sure how to go about this way.

Comment: In macos, you can use `grep -f /dev/stdin -q ./results.log` to read the pattern from standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to merge the log file and the output of the program into a new log file:

```
sort -u <(./scan_network.py 22 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20) results.log > newresults.log
```

The `-u` flag causes duplicate lines to be removed from the output, so you will get only one of each line.

That has the side effect of reordering the lines (so that they are sorted alphabetically). It is possible to preserve order if necessary, but it gets more complicated.

With a reasonably modern gnu `sort`, you can use a "version number" sort, which will do a reasonable job of keeping IP numbers in logical order; you can use the `-V` flag to do that. Or you can sort the octets individually with `sort -u -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n ...`. Or you can just live with lexicographic ordering. Do not just use `-n` for standard numeric sorting, because it will only examine the first octet, and that will have an unfortunate interaction with the `-u` option, since two lines which compare equal are considered duplicates. As numeric sort only considers the numeric prefix, there will be many false duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't mind sorting and rewriting your log file, [rici's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856506/45375) works well** (note that simply using `-V` for true per-component numerical IP-address sorting is *not* an option on macOS, unfortunately).<sup>[1]</sup>.

Here's an **alternative that only appends to the existing log file on demand, in-place, without reordering existing lines**:

```
grep -f results.log -xFv <(./scan_network.py 22 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20) >> results.log
```

Note: This assumes that `./scan_network.py`'s output is line-based; pipe to `tr` to transform to line-based output, if necessary.

- `-f` treats each line in the specified file as a separate search term, where a match of any term is considered an overall match.
- `-x` matches lines in full
- `-F` performs *literal* matching (doesn't interpret search terms as regular expressions)
- `-v` only outputs lines that do *not* match

The net effect is that only lines output by `./scan_network.py ...` that aren't already present in `results.log` are appended to `results.log`.

Note, however, that performance will likely suffer the larger `results.log` becomes, so rici's approach may be preferable in the long run, particularly, if the log file keeps growing and/or you want the log sorted by IP addresses anyway.

---

As for **what you've tried**:

- Both GNU and BSD/macOS `grep` optionally accept `-` as a placeholder for stdin to accept the *input* from, but note that this operand is never needed, because `grep` reads input from stdin by default.
- By contrast, only *GNU* `grep` accepts `-` as the *option-argument* to `-f`, i.e., the file containing the *search terms* to apply.
  BSD/macOS requires either an explicit filename, a process substitution (as above), or, in a pinch, `/dev/stdin` to refer to stdin.
- The logic of your search must be reversed: as in the command above, the existing log file contents must serve as the search terms (passed to `-f`), and the `./scan_network.py ...` output must serve as the input in order to determine which lines are *not* (`-v`) already in the log file.
- using `-` to represent stdin *or* stdout, depending on context, is a mere *convention* that only works as a command *argument*, so your attempt to refer to stdout output with `if ...; then - >> results.log` cannot work, because `-` is invariably interpreted as a *command name*.
- If you use `grep -q`, stdout output is by definition *suppressed*, so there's nothing to pass on (even if you used a pipe).

---

<sup>[1] macOS's (OS X's) `sort` does *not* support `-V` for per-component version-number sorting (which can be applied to IP addresses too). Even though the macOS `sort` *is* a *GNU* `sort`, it is an *ancient* one - v5.93 as of macOS 10.12 - that predates support for `-V`.</sup>

Comment: The way you explained this makes sense to me. Do you think between your suggestion and rici's suggestion that either of them would be better in terms of performance?

Comment: @isema: The more data is involved, the better rici's approach will perform by comparison, I think, but with small input sets and log files it may not matter. If your log file keeps growing, I'd go with rici's approach. If you're willing to run a few experiments, do share the results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script returns a single line of text, you can store the output in a variable and then grep for that string. For example:

```
logfile="results.log"

# save output to a shell variable
str=$(./scan_network.py 22 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.20)

# don't call grep twice for the same pattern    
grep=$(grep -F "$str" "$logfile")

# append if grep results are empty
if [[ -z "$grep" ]]; then
    echo "$grep" >> "$logfile"
fi
```

Comment: Not quite, the script prints multiple lines each containing the IP address, in this instance, of any host that responds on port 22.

Comment: @isema This is why you need to post actual input and output. It's not reasonable to expect others to play "guess what my data looks like!"